# How to preload memory with given raw bytes in gem5 from the command line in addition to the main ELF executable?

Tags: gem5

I need memory to be setup in a given way immediately when simulation starts before any instructions are executed.

I understand that this is essentially what the ELF loader does to load the main executable, but trying to pass `fs.py --kernel` multiple times appears to have no effect.

I could try to hack that data into my mail ELF executable with the linker script, but it would be much more convenient if I could avoid this and just provide either raw bytes on the CLI, or give a raw binary file to be loaded at a given address.

QEMU for example exposes this type of functionality [with `-device loader`](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/60905286cb5150de854e08279bca7dfc4b549e91/docs/generic-loader.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Tested in gem5 f5f9ca46258ac2ded8f3402e5d271a18f8400183 (April 2020) I can achieve this with:

```
configs/example/fs.py \
  --param 'system.workload.extras = "mydata.raw"' \
  --param 'system.workload.extras_addrs = 0x83000000' \
```

where `mydata.raw` contains the raw data to be loaded, and `0x83000000` is the base physical address to load to.

Both of those parameters are arrays, so you can load multiple raw binaries for example with:

```
configs/example/fs.py \
  --param 'system.workload.extras = ["mydata.raw", "mydata2.raw"]' \
  --param 'system.workload.extras_addrs = [0x83000000, 0x84000000]' \
```

This can be used for example to pass information to baremetal executables. For example, this [could be used to implement baremetal command line arguments of a C program](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/commit/b7887ac06bd7fc8011fbf595b1d50ea67960d28c).